# How to implement precision, recall and f1-score for recurrent neural network?

Tags: python, keras, classification, precision, recurrent-neural-network

Is there any way to calculate precision, recall and f1-score for binary classification in sequential problem? I have 10s audio files and my training is not efficient (my model is many-to-many). Everytime in such situation I was implementing those functions and put it as a metrics in keras, but it was for simple convolutional neural networks. I just wonder if something similar is possible in RNN?

Comment: Well... have you tried? Most likely you can re-use the same metrics regardless of layer types.

Comment: Ok, I don't why but I assumed it is something different. Thanks a lot!